# How can I get Blender to just do Matcap shading for the selected object?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, matcaps

I have noticed that the behavior of MatCap shading has changed in recent versions of Blender (at least by 2.72b). When I turn Matcap on, all objects are shaded with the same Matcap texture. For sculpting, I only want the selected object shaded with Matcap (as in numerous tutorials).

How can I get it to just do Matcap shading for the selected object (primarily in Sculpt mode)?

Even better would be if we could select a different MatCap material by object or vertex group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid you can do it now only in blender internal in GLSL shading. But that shouldn't matter if you want it for sculpting. You only need some [matcap textures](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/release/datafiles/matcaps/). Here is what to set:

[image]

Good thing is you can setup as many matcaps as you want for your objects:)

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks very much.  After a little searching I found the Blender matcap .jpg files and your setup did the trick.  Now I need to find more matcaps and figure out how to convert ZBrush matcaps for use in Blender (I don't currently own a copy).